# lp & Epson WF: set quality of printing

Tags: printing, printer, lp

I use Epson WF 7510 printer, and I can print in any quality I choose (draft/normal/best) using system tools (OS X). But I cannot change the quality of printing in command line: `lp -o EPIJ_Qual=...` has no effect.

How can I change the quality of print?

The output of `lpoptions -l` is as follows:

```
EPIJ_PSrc/Page Setup: *2 3
EPIJ_Size/Paper Size: 1 74 76 6 23 *0 10 2 3 70 28 29 97 7 25 27 112 26 4 5
EPIJ_Medi/Media Type: *0 12 92 13 15 97 117 93
EPIJ_Ink_/Grayscale: *1 0
EPIJ_Mode/Mode: *0 3
EPIJ_APri/Automatic: 0 *1 2
EPIJ_Manu/Custom: *0
EPIJ_Qual/Print Quality: 301 302 303 *304 305 306 307
EPIJ_Hori/Mirror Image: *0 1
EPIJ_CMat/Color Settings: *0 1 2 3
EPIJ_CCor/Mode: 3 *6
EPIJ_Gamm/Gamma: 0 *1
EPIJ_UEpL/EPSON Color LUT: *0 1
EPIJ_ERGB/E-RGB: *0 1
EPIJ_ECAv/Advanced Settings: *0 1
EPIJ_Brit/Brightness: -25 -24 -23 -22 -21 -20 -19 -18 -17 -16 -15 -14 -13 -12 -11 -10 -9 -8 -7 -6 -5 -4 -3 -2 -1 *0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25
EPIJ_Cont/Contrast: -25 -24 -23 -22 -21 -20 -19 -18 -17 -16 -15 -14 -13 -12 -11 -10 -9 -8 -7 -6 -5 -4 -3 -2 -1 *0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25
EPIJ_Satu/Saturation: -25 -24 -23 -22 -21 -20 -19 -18 -17 -16 -15 -14 -13 -12 -11 -10 -9 -8 -7 -6 -5 -4 -3 -2 -1 *0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25
EPIJ_Cyan/Cyan: -25 -24 -23 -22 -21 -20 -19 -18 -17 -16 -15 -14 -13 -12 -11 -10 -9 -8 -7 -6 -5 -4 -3 -2 -1 *0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25
EPIJ_Mage/Magenta: -25 -24 -23 -22 -21 -20 -19 -18 -17 -16 -15 -14 -13 -12 -11 -10 -9 -8 -7 -6 -5 -4 -3 -2 -1 *0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25
EPIJ_Yell/Yellow: -25 -24 -23 -22 -21 -20 -19 -18 -17 -16 -15 -14 -13 -12 -11 -10 -9 -8 -7 -6 -5 -4 -3 -2 -1 *0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25
EPIJ_ATon/Scene Correction: *7 11 12 13 4 8
EPIJ_AFil/Sharpen: *0 1
EPIJ_AGai/Sharpness Option: *1 2
EPIJ_ACam/Digital Camera Correction: *0 1
EPIJ_DCCT/Image Purelyzer Option: *0 1
EPIJ_OSColMat/ColorMatching: *1 2
EPIJ_HdofClSp/Use Generic RGB: 0 *1
EPIJ_OSCMProf/CustomColorMatchingProfile: *0 1 2 3
EPIJ_REye/Fix Red-Eye: *0 1
EPIJ_Bdls/Borderless: *0 1
EPIJ_exmg/Expansion: 0 1 *2
EPIJProfileSpec/EPSON Profile: *0 1
ColorModel/ColorModel: *RGB Mono
MediaType/MediaType: *0 12 92 13 15 97 117 93
Resolution/Resolution: 120x120dpi 360x360dpi *720x720dpi
PageSize/Media Size: *A4 A4.NMgn EPKG EPKG.NMgn EPPhotoPaper2L EPPhotoPaper2L.NMgn A6 A5 A3 A3.NMgn EP13x19 EP13x19.NMgn B4 B5 EPPhotoPaperLRoll EPPhotoPaperLRoll.NMgn EPIndexCard5x8 EP8x10in EPHiVision102x180 EPHiVision102x180.NMgn EP100x148mm EP100x148mm.NMgn Env10 EnvDL EnvC4 EnvC6 Letter Legal Custom.WIDTHxHEIGHT
EPIJ_BSSv/Skip Blank Page: *0 1
EPIJ_Silt/Quiet Mode: *0 1
EPIJ_BkPr/Permit temporary black printing: *0 1
EPIJ_OPT_Bi_D/High Speed Printing: 0 *1
EPIJ_ENAL/Warning Notifications: 1-0_2-0_3-0_4-0 *1-1_2-1_3-1_4-1
```

Usage of other options like `-o EPIJ_Hori=1` has effect.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with the option `-o print-quality=3` or 4/5 ?
For example:

```
lp -o print-quality=3 filename
```

Reference: [lpr man page](https://www.cups.org/doc/man-lpr.html)

With an Epson SX405 under Ubuntu 18.04, it doesn't work.
I typed `lpoptions -l | grep [Qq]uality`, it gives:

```
StpQuality/Print Quality: None Economy Draft *Standard High Photo HighPhoto UltraPhoto Best
StpBandEnhancement/Quality Enhancement: *None 0 1 2 3 4
```

then `lp -o StpQuality=Economy filename` worked...

Comment: Sorry I cannot test it, I do not have that printer anymore.